# How can i set http headers in htaccess only for IE 9

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am not able to find and way to set some header in .htaccess file only if the browser is IE9. Pseudo code for my requirement is:

```
if(ie 9) {
 header set ( value2)  
} else {
      header set ( value2)
}
```

Please suggest me how i can achieve this in my htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [BrowserMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#browsermatch) directive from `mod_setenvif` to set Apache environment variable and use this variable to set appropriate header value using [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html).

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE 9" MSIE9FOUND
Header set YourHeader value2 env=MSIE9FOUND
```